# Let $G$ a finite group. If $A$ is a group of automorphisms of $G$, the subgroup $[G,A]$ is an $A$-invariant normal subgroup in $G$?

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, automorphism-group

By definition, $$[G,A] = \big<[g,\alpha] = g^{-1}g^\alpha; g \in G, \alpha \in A \big>.$$
For normality part, for any $x \in G$ we have $[g,\alpha]^x = (g^{-1}g^\alpha)^x = (g^x)^{-1}g^{\alpha x}$ and I don't know if it belongs to $[G,A]$.

For the A invariant part, let $\beta \in A$,
$[g,\alpha]^\beta = (g^{-1}g^\alpha)^\beta = (g^\beta)^{-1}g^{\alpha \beta}$ does it belongs to $[G,A]$?

Comment: $g^\alpha =\alpha(g)$?

Comment: I don't remember where but I've seen that notation in the literature, @JCAA.

Comment: Yes, is the automorphism $\alpha$ acting on g

Comment: @JCAA Kurtzweil book is written this way

Comment: I do not argue about notation. I asked for clarification and I got it.

Comment: @JCAA nor do I, I just thought that is where you might have stumbled upon it.

Comment: Note that $[gx,\alpha] = [g,\alpha]^x[x,\alpha]$, proving invariance under $G$, and invariance under $A$ is similar: consider $[g,\alpha\beta]$.

Comment: Thanks @DerekHolt, it is clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the semidirect product $H=GA$ of $G$ (normal) and $A$. Then $[G, A]=[G, H]$ which is indeed a normal subgroup of $H$ inside $G$.